# Tensor and Matrices

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

Suppose that we are dealing with the following matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{00} & a_{01} \\ a_{10} & a_{11}\end{bmatrix}$$
but I don't want to use matrix notation, insted I want to use tensor notation, so I write this matrix as:
$$A^{\mu}_{\nu}$$
**Question is:** $A^0_1$ is equal to $a_{01}$ or $a_{10}$? And from which convention rule this comes from? And If I have $A_{\mu\nu}$ (or $A^{\mu\nu}$) instead?
I searched around and I didn't find nothing regarding this.

Now this is an abstract situation but this problem can become really influential once we start talking about the $F_{\mu\nu}$ matrix in relativistic electromagnetism for example.

Comment: Did you mean to write $A^{\mu}{}_{\nu}$ slanted rather than $A^{\mu}_{\nu}$?

Comment: The notation $A^\mu_\nu$ is sloppy.
You need to write either $A^\mu{}_\nu$ or $A_\nu{}^ \mu$.
Otherwise it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, in tensor index notation the order of indices matters.  If there's one upstairs index and one downstairs index, then one should either write $A^\mu_{\ \ \nu}$ or $A_\nu^{\ \ \mu}$.  Traditionally the first index (whether upper or lower) is used to designate the row, and the second is used to designate the column, so for example $A^0_{\ \ 1}=a_{01}$.

Your next question gets to the heart of why it's dangerous to naively say that a tensor with two indices is simply a matrix.   In linear algebra, we often first deal with objects which eat vectors and spit out other vectors, e.g.

$$\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2}=\pmatrix{m_{11}&m_{12}\\m_{21}&m_{22}}\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}$$

Such an object is a $(1,1)$-tensor, and the above equation would be written $a^\mu = m^\mu_{\ \ \nu} b^\nu$.  $(1,1)$-tensors have familiar properties, such as the fact that their trace and determinant are basis-independent.

$(2,0)$-tensors and $(0,2)$-tensors can also be laid out in matrix form.  This is a convenient way to write out what their components are.  For example, on often says that the Minkowski metric, a $(0,2)$-tensor, is given by

$$\eta = \pmatrix{-1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}$$

This is perfectly fine.  However, it's critical to remember that e.g. the determinants and traces of such objects are *not* basis independent, and their transformation rules under basis changes are different.

So, to answer your question if you write down a couple of rows and columns of numbers, it's impossible to tell the difference between a $(1,1)$-tensor, a $(0,2)$-tensor, or a $(2,0)$-tensor without knowing how it transforms when you change bases, and knowing the difference is critical to understanding the properties of the tensor in question.

Answer (score 4):

It depends whether you want the matrix to represent a linear map or a quadratic form. In the former case you should replace  $a_{\mu\nu}$ by ${A^\mu}_\nu$, so that ${\bf y}={\bf A}{\bf x}$ becomes
$$
y^\nu= {A^\mu}_\nu x^\nu
$$
and in the latter case $Q[{\bf x}]={\bf x}^T {\bf A}{\bf x}$ becomes
$$
Q= A_{\mu\nu}x^\mu x^\nu.
$$
The different placement of the indices reflects how the matrices change under a change of basis. A linear map transforms as ${\bf A}\to {\bf D}^{-1} {\bf A}{\bf D}$ (a *similarity* transformation) while a quadratic form transforms as $  {\bf A}\to {\bf D}^T {\bf A}{\bf D}$ (a *congruence* transformation) This makes a big difference when you have to diagonalize the matrices.